# iOS darkmode: image resized in signature switch background content with white

Tags: ios, email, background-color, ios-darkmode

I am creating an email signature for a Gmail account.

That is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/Geo87/pk3o2vhr/14/
The procedure to implement the email signature in Gmail is the following:

1. Open the HTML file in a browser
2. Copy the content of the HTML file
3. Paste into the Gmail > Settings > Signature

**The problem:**

I want to use an image double-size (210x140px) in order to have the picture really sharp on mobile devices or retina screen.

All work fine, expect on Mail (iOS) on dark mode - I cannot try on other dark mode devices.

I don't understand why, if I resize the image in CSS or HTML, and I send an email, the recipient receives the email with the body text background in white color.

I tried to change CSS (`id` and `class`), I put the size in the HTML with attribute `width` and `height` but doesn't work, still the white background.
I've tried to upload an image in 144dpi, but Gmail automatically resized it in 72dpi. So the effect is not the sharp image I want.

On the email on the left (*img 144*) you can see the image resized in 72dpi and the right effect. On the right, you have the "bug" I see on iOS.

**Do you have any idea why?**
**Did you have the same problem?**

Thank you in advance,
Best
Geo

[image: Screen of two emails, left with an image with the correct size, right with an email resized]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've literally just spent hours trying to figure out a similar issue. A small PNG at 100% with no width/height attributes or style in the signature results in a dark background in dark mode, but of course with a fuzzy image on hi-res devices. A larger PNG with size attributes/CSS ends up with a white background, even with a width="100%" in a table cell. I've been trying every combo of things I can think of to get it to behave and am about to give up because I think this is some weird bug.

Comment: Nope... unfortunately I didn't ...